# How to save date of last application run-time?

Tags: c#, .net

My current approach is to store date in .settings file and update it at the end of program, but it doesn't work.

code:

```
Settings.Default.RunTime = DateTime.Today;
Settings.Default.Save();
```

how to fix it?

Comment: A little more information would be useful. Do you get errors? After setting the value and saving it, when you immediately (i.e. before app shutdown) read the value from the settings file, does it give the correct one? And I suppose you use: Properties.Settings.Default.Runtime?

Comment: What does, "It doesn't work" mean?  Are you able to read the value the next time you start up?  Does it throw an exception?  Is the value not correct?  Perhaps you want `DateTime.Now`, which gives the date and time rather than `DateTime.Today` which only gives the current date with a time of 00:00:00.

Comment: It might be because you are trying to modify the default instead of the current.

Comment: Make sure it is a 'User' Setting and not an 'Application' Setting

Comment: I had no exceptions just after my program run i checked .settings file and date value was not changed into proper one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Properties** -> **Settings**, make sure the name of the setting is "RunTime", the type is "System.DateTime", and the scope is "user". After that, you should be able to use the following code:

```
// Access setting    
Properties.Settings.Default.RunTime= DateTime.Today;
// Save all settings
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

If you would like more information on application settings, check out this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx).